# Cannot read data from SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an application that gets the first name and last name from user and inserts them into a database, then the user can write the first name in another field and search for the last name, and the program should show the last name of the searched name in the TextView.

```
package ir.itstuff.dbtest;

import java.util.List;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText fName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText sName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Button btdt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FirstName varchar,SecondName varchar)");

        final String first_name = fName.getText().toString();
        final String second_name = sName.getText().toString();
        final String search_name = et3.getText().toString();
        // Inserting data from inputs
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName,SecondName) VALUES ('"
                        + first_name + "','" + second_name + "')");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Inserted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                db.close();

            }
        });
        btdt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE FirstName='"+search_name+"'");
                Cursor c;
                c = db.query(false, "MyTable",null, "FirstName="+search_name, null, null, null, null, null);
                while(c.moveToNext()){
                    String result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LastName"));
                    tv.setText(result);
                }
                db.close();

            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

It works fine till the program inserts the data to the database, but when i search for a name, the program crashes.
This is the log cat output:

```
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848): Process: ir.itstuff.dbtest, PID: 1848
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE FirstName=
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at ir.itstuff.dbtest.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:60)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-30 08:55:14.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing the database and then trying to use it again without opening it. When someone clicks on `btdt`, the database is closed. You need to open it again before querying by the first name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but i just fixed the database problem as you said, but still it crashes.

Comment: Is it the same error? What does the stack trace say?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your query. Make sure things like column names are correct. In any case, the original problem is solved and you should mark the answer correct to close the question. Try to fix the new problem; if you don't succeed, you can post a new question.

Comment: I suspect when the view is clicked the search string is empty, so your where condition becomes `FirstName=`, which SQLite will not understand. You can wrap the search string with single quotes so that even an empty string will work, like so: `"FirstName='" + search_name + "'"`. For an empty string, this will yield `FirstName=''`, which SQLite will accept.

Comment: You should also get the text from the `EditText` inside of the `onClick` callback. Right now you are doing it in `onCreate`, where the text is probably empty, and using that final string whenever `onClick` is called, even if the text has changed.

Comment: you somehow solved my problem, and I really appreciate it, but someone has voted down my question and i lost my reputations, :( i don't know why those experts cannot understand newbies, they should notice that they were newbies before, too!

Answer (score 0):

As per your edit, your problem seems to be in the query:

Use `?` in your query and android will parse the value in.

Something like:

```
final String selectQuery = "SELECT " + BACKUP_TABLE_NAME + ".*, " + BACKUPCONTACTS_TABLE_NAME + "." + BACKUPCONTACTS_ID + ", "
                + BACKUPCONTACTS_TABLE_NAME + "." + BACKUPCONTACTS_VCARD + ", " + BACKUPCONTACTS_TABLE_NAME + "." + BACKUPCONTACTS_DISPLAY_NAME 
                + " FROM " + BACKUP_TABLE_NAME + ", " + BACKUPCONTACTS_TABLE_NAME 
                + " WHERE " + BACKUP_TABLE_NAME + "." + BACKUP_ID + " = " + BACKUPCONTACTS_TABLE_NAME+ "." + BACKUPCONTACTS_ID_BACKUP_FK 
                + " AND " + BACKUP_TABLE_NAME + "." + BACKUP_ID + " = ?";

        final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

So, in your case it will be:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE FirstName " + " = ? "

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{search_name});
```

Tip: Use camel case to name your variables, and not underscores. That is the java convention. So, `search_name` would be renamed to `searchName`

Answer (score -1):

First of all your create table query is not correct. Because SQLite does not support varchar datatype. Instead of varchar use TEXT datatype and then ,

try this  instead of your syntax to get the cursor from the table records

```
  c = db.query("MyTable",null,"FirstName=?",new String[]{FirstName }, null, null, null, null);
```